# How to use allocation instrument in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, instruments, allocation

Hi I did the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *str = @"ok";

    int count=0;
    while (count < 20)
    {
        count++;
        [arr addObject:str];
        NSLog( @"arr is %@",arr );
        if (count == 200)
        {
            NSLog(@"out");
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

and I'm getting unbounded memory growth. How to find it through instrument? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling `release` on an `autorelease`d object?

Comment: i disabled ARC for knowing how instruments will work.

Comment: @murali, [NSArray array] returns autoreleased object, so you should not release it in any case

Comment: ok i just modified my code. but it still giving unbounded memory growth graph

Comment: How often is that view being loaded?

Comment: only one time.but please observe the code which is in for loop giving that graph i think so

Comment: No that code looks fine (apart from the pointless `if` statement that won't ever be `YES`).

Comment: Have you already solved your problem